# HMS - certificate fingerprint error code: 907122045

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

[getToken] Error/Exception: {"nativeStackAndroid":[],"userInfo":null,"message":"6003: certificate fingerprint error","code":"907122045","line":2242,"column":45,"sourceURL":""} WHEN INSTALL APP in APPGALLERY

FYI: App Signing has already been applied for this app

Answer (score 1):

In app signing function, it will replace the application signature.

You need to check the new signature is configured in Appgallery console:
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/config-agc-0000001050196065#section19713716202718

If it is missing, you will meet this error.

Answer (score 1):

**Error code 6003** is caused by inconsistent certificate fingerprint configurations. Check whether the correct certificate fingerprint is configured in AppGallery Connect. For details; see AppGallery Connect configuration in Development Preparations.

**Check the following items:**

Verify that the fingerprint has been configured, and the certificate for packing the signature on the local client is the same as the certificate for configuring the fingerprint on the server.
Check the fingerprint entries in the certificate. It is recommended that you use a single entry.
If error code 6003 persists when you run the local client after the fingerprint is configured, the debug certificate is running by default. Clear the cache of HMS Core (APK) and run the client again.
For details , please refer to FAQ:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/rn-faqs-0000001057278103

Please refer to below link for configuring fingerprint:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/config-agc-0000001053537946